# Store time related things in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to store time related information in my graph, for nodes and relations.
Ideally, in a programming language, I would use a sorted map, storing as keys the dates and as attribute each value (for example price) associated, e.g. a PERSON that would have a map called "paid" and entries like "2016/02/12",2;"2016/03/21",5;.....
Same thing for relations: a relation between a restaurant and a PERSON would have the same map, called "paid" to know when and how much.

In Neo4J, I don't really know. I could store 2 arrays as properties, one with the dates and one with the price, but the problem is how do I insert respecting the order (last inserted does not mean newer), and how do I query: I want all the relations that have a date between X and Y. This does not seem trivial to me in Cypher.

Another idea I had is to create one relation per date. This makes the graph have a huge load of relations between the same nodes, but it is easier to query. This doesn't solve the problem for the nodes, only for the relations.

I saw on here another solution: add a property for each date, e.g. Person.2016/02/12=2, Person.2016/03/21=5 etc...
The problem in that Neo4J doesn't accept this type of naming for properties AND I don't see how to query this by dates.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

--edit--
Actually, I will need a lot of Payment nodes (basically one a day, every day, during years, for dozens of thousands of nodes), and adding payment nodes will make my graph grow a lot. Actually, I managed to do the insert, etc...in Java so basically I will always have the two arrays sorted in my nodes/relations...what I don't know is if I can query the graph for, for example, the index of the entry of the array "dates" that would be >= date1 and the index of the entry of the array "dates" that would be <= date2

Answer (score 0):

When you need multiple values for a property, you can always introduce nodes: instead of having a `paid` property, you can link to `Payment` nodes:

```
CREATE (p:Person {uid: 1})
# Add multiple payments, that can be queried by date
CREATE (p)-[:IS_PAID {date: "2016-02-12"}]->(:Payment {amount: 2})
CREATE (p)-[:IS_PAID {date: "2016-03-21"}]->(:Payment {amount: 5})
```

You could also use a numeric value for the date (e.g. timestamp). You can then query it easily:

```
MATCH (p:Person {uid: 1})-[rel:IS_PAID]->(p:Payment)
WHERE "2016-02-01" <= rel.date < "2016-03-01"
RETURN sum(p.amount) AS total
```

You can also do a similar thing in the context of relationships, to avoid creating "duplicate" relationships which just contain different payment data, representing a hypergraph:

```
CREATE (p:Person {uid: 1}), (r:Restaurant {uid: 1})
# Create an archetype of a meal (a person in a restaurant)
CREATE (p)-[:HAS_MEAL]->(m:Meal)<-[:SERVES_MEAL]-(r)
# Add multiple payments for actual meals
CREATE (m)-[:IS_PAID {date: "2016-02-12"}]->(:Payment {amount: 2})
CREATE (m)-[:IS_PAID {date: "2016-03-21"}]->(:Payment {amount: 5})
```

You get 2 relationships and a node instead of a single relationship, but then it can be reused for all the payments and you keep a single path between the Person and the Restaurant, which you might need in a query which doesn't use the payments.

It's queried as easily as the node before:

- the total paid by a person at a specific restaurant in February:

  ```
  MATCH (p:Person {uid: 1}), (r:Restaurant {uid: 1})
  MATCH (p)-[:HAS_MEAL]->(m:Meal)<-[:SERVES_MEAL]-(r)
  MATCH (m)-[rel:IS_PAID]->(p)
  WHERE "2016-02-01" <= r.date < "2016-03-01"
  RETURN sum(p.amount) AS total
  ```
- the total paid by a person in February, per restaurant:

  ```
  MATCH (p:Person {uid: 1})
  MATCH (p)-[:HAS_MEAL]->(m:Meal)<-[:SERVES_MEAL]-(r:Restaurant)
  MATCH (m)-[rel:IS_PAID]->(p:Payment)
  WHERE "2016-02-01" <= r.date < "2016-03-01"
  RETURN r, sum(p.amount) AS total
  ```
- the restaurants visited by a person in February:

  ```
  MATCH (p:Person {uid: 1})
  MATCH (p)-[:HAS_MEAL]->(m:Meal)<-[:SERVES_MEAL]-(r:Restaurant)
  MATCH (m)-[rel:IS_PAID]->(:Payment)
  WHERE "2016-02-01" <= r.date < "2016-03-01"
  RETURN DISTINCT r
  ```
- the restaurants 2 persons have both visited:

  ```
  MATCH (p1:Person {uid: 1}), (p2:Person {uid: 2})
  MATCH (p1)-[:HAS_MEAL]->(:Meal)<-[:SERVES_MEAL]-(r:Restaurant),
        (p2)-[:HAS_MEAL]->(:Meal)<-[:SERVES_MEAL]-(r)
  RETURN r
  ```
- etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Frank, That is a solution about which I did not think, and I have to say it is quite elegant for the restaurant example, but my application is not exactly this, and I will need a lot of Payment nodes (basically one a day, every day, during years, for dozens of thousands of nodes), and this will make my graph grow a lot. I would really like to keep it as properties.

Comment: Still, it's a graph database, it knows how to manage nodes and relationships. But yeah, I don't know your use cases, I just imagined a few queries based on your short example. They have the advantage of filtering early, to avoid loading too much data, whereas if you put lots of properties on one node, they could all be loaded whether you need them or not.